# Sanitizing, Validating , etc (Plugin)

Tags: plugins

I am currently developing my first WordPress plugin. A few days ago I submitted it to WordPress for review. Unfortunately, the plugin was not (yet) published, because I still have to close some security issues.

I don't Know How to fix it

**## Data Must be Sanitized, Escaped, and Validated**

contador2022/wp_mvpcounter.php:240: $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

**## Variables and options must be escaped when echo'd**

contador2022/manage/admin.php:460: <?php echo $query_today;

**## Generic function/class/define/namespace names**

contador2022/wp_mvpcounter.php:12:class PostViewsStats

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the [Plugin Security section](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/) in the plugin developer's handbook.

### 1) Data Must be Sanitized, Escaped, and Validated

**Validation** – These are the checks that are run to ensure the data you have is
what it should be. For instance, an e-mail looks like an e-mail
address, that a date is a date, and that a number is (or is cast as)
an integer.

**Sanitization / Escaping** – These are the filters that are applied to data to make it 'safe' in a specific context. For instance, to display HTML code in a text area it would be necessary to replace all the HTML tags by their entity equivalents

**Before** : `$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`

**After** : `$ua = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) : '';`

### 2) Variables and options must be escaped when echoing

When you are going to print any content as output and if you did not properly escape it then will generate an error and will say Output should be run through an escaping function. Check out more functions [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/)

**Before**: `echo $query_today;`

**After** : `echo esc_html( $query_today );`

### 3) Generic function/class/define/namespace names

All plugins must have unique function names, namespaces, defines, and class names. This prevents your plugin from conflicting with other plugins or themes. You can add your unique prefix or suffix to every function and class name.

**Before**: `class PostViewsStats`

**After**: `class GunviperPostViewsStats`

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' $ua = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) : '';

Comment: It works perfectly in my editor.

Comment: Your editor may need to be reloaded. There is a possibility that the error originated elsewhere.

Comment: thank you very much,  works